# Serial port not working on Ubuntu Mate RaspberryPI 3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, serial-port, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am using a RaspberryPI 3 and a GPRS/GPS devKit from Ublox. Using Raspbian and the code I post below I am able to establish a gprs connection and get access to internet through the gprs module and a USB/Serial connection. However, the same code on an Ubuntu Mate distro on the same Raspberry PI 3 won't work, giving me an "can't open port" error.

What is the difference and why is it working on Raspbian and not on Ubuntu Mate? Is this maybe an issue with port naming between linux distros?

thanks!

Code to establish connection through serial port : ( info : I use semaphores to control the output of each command and launch them in the correct order )

```
import com.pi4j.io.serial.Serial;
import com.pi4j.io.serial.SerialDataEvent;
import com.pi4j.io.serial.SerialDataListener;
import com.pi4j.io.serial.SerialFactory;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.functions.Action1;

/**
 *
 * @author daniel.cardoza
 */
public final class Gsm {

    private final Serial serial = SerialFactory.createInstance();
    private static String DEVICE_PORT = "/dev/ttyACM0";
    private static int BAUD_RATE = 115200;
    private int test = 0;

    //COMMANDS

    public static String OPEN_ECM_DATA_CONNECTION = "AT+UCEDATA=2,0";
    public static String CHECK_PIN = "AT+CPIN?";
    public static String GPS_REQUEST = "AT+ULOC=2,3,1,5,10\r";
    public static String RESULT_CODE_OK = "\r\nOK\r\n";
    public static String TEXT_RESPONSE_ULOC = "+UULOC:";
    public static String INTERNAL_CONTEXT = "AT+UPSDA=0,3";
    public static String AGNSS_CONF = "AT+UGSRV=\"cell-live1.services.u-blox.com\",\"cell-live2.services.u-blox.com\",\"J-aI_-ZUNEef7ZGUv67LJw\",14,4,1,65,0,15�";
    public static String AGNSS_LOG = "AT+UGIND=1";
    public static String AGNSS_LOCATION_LOG = "AT+ULOCIND=1";
    public static String ERROR = "AT+CMEE=2";

    ArrayList<String> commandConfig = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> commandConfigResponse = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

    public Gsm() {

    }

    //Opening the AT and Data cghannel
    public boolean connect() {
        try {
            System.out.println("conectamos");
            serial.open(DEVICE_PORT, BAUD_RATE);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //log
            System.out.println(" Error : " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }


    public void init()
    {

        commandConfig.add(CHECK_PIN);
        commandConfig.add(ERROR);
        commandConfig.add(CONNECT_GPRS);
        commandConfig.add(OPEN_ECM_DATA_CONNECTION);

            serial.addListener(new SerialDataListener() {
                @Override
                public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("event data : " + event.getData());
                    semaphore.release();

                }
            });

        Observable<String> observable = Observable.from(commandConfig);
        observable.subscribe(new Action1<String>() 
            {
                public void call(String command) {

                   System.out.println("command : " + command);

                    try {
                        semaphore.acquire();
                        serial.writeln(command);
                        System.out.println("test " + test);
                        test++;
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Gsm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                }
            });

 }



    //Configuration of CDC-ECM channel
    public void initialConfiguration() {

        System.out.println("error");

        commandConfig.add(ERROR);
        System.out.println("connect gprs");

        commandConfig.add(CONNECT_GPRS);
        final String ultimoComando;

        try {
            serial.addListener(new SerialDataListener() {
                @Override
                public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("event data : " + event.getData());

                }
            });

            System.out.println("check pin");
            serial.writeln(OPEN_ECM_DATA_CONNECTION);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //log
            System.out.println(" Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

And the main method called is :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gsm gsm = new Gsm();
        System.out.println("Empezamos la ejecución del programa");
        if(gsm.connect())
        {
            System.out.println("connection successful");
            gsm.init();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("connection error");
        }
        //gsm.initialConfiguration();



    }
```